# Do I have to recheck bags when changing planes? (US to Europe)

Tags: luggage

I am flying from Austin to Houston; then Houston to Frankfurt; and then Frankfurt to Nuremberg. When do I have to claim bags and then recheck them?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. We cannot answer your question definitively unless you tell us whether your entire itinerary is on a single ticket, or if you bought multiple tickets, and which airlines are operating each segment. Please [edit] your post to include this information.

Comment: @choster Why does it matter what airlines are involved?

Comment: It matters because not all airlines interline.

Answer (score 2):

From the perspective of legal requirements, you will not need to collect your bags anywhere before Nuremberg.  The US does not require you to collect bags when departing the country (only when entering), and Europe does not require you to collect them except for at your final destination with very few exceptions (and this is certainly not one).

I am presuming that your flights were all booked on a single ticket (United connecting to Lufthansa I'd presume).  If they were not, then the conditions of the airlines might override the legalities and you may need to collect them, but as you haven't stated the airlines involved of whether the flights were purchased as one ticket or multiple it's impossible to say.

(FWIW, I flew a very similar route to Nuremberg in December)

Comment: Let's emphasise the fact that this is valid in the Austin -> Houston -> Frankfurt -> Nuremberg direction. The other way around, checked luggage will have to be claimed at the first port of entry in the US (Houston if the itinerary is exactly the same in the reverse direction) and then dropped at the counter just after going through customs.